# How to fix color interval in heatmap2 for different matrices?

Tags: r

I'm using heatmap2 function in R. I'm creating heatmaps for different matrices and at the end I want to compare them.I have defined my color pallet and I'm using same color pallet for different matrices, but problem is that after plotting color key interval is different for different heatmaps(for one is from -.0.2 to 0.2 and for other one is from -0.15 to 0.2) and they are not really comparable.
Would someone help me to fix this?
Here is my effort:

```
colors = c(seq(min(Gold),-0.0002,length=100),seq(-0.0003,0.0002,length=20),seq(0.0003,max(Gold),length=100))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","white","yellow", "red"))(n = 219)


# Creat heatmap for two matrices:


pdf("Gold1.pdf")
heatmap.2(Gold,Colv=as.dendrogram(hcr),Rowv=as.dendrogram(hc), col=my_palette, scale="none" , key=TRUE, symkey=FALSE, symm=F,symbreaks=T,cexRow=1,cexCol=1,margins=c(6,11),labRow = "" ,trace="none",keysize = 1.2,density.info="none",main="Ground truth",srtCol=90)

heatmap.2(mtlcof,Colv=as.dendrogram(hcr),Rowv=as.dendrogram(hc), col=my_palette, scale="none" , key=TRUE, symkey=FALSE, symm=F,symbreaks=T,cexRow=1,cexCol=1,margins=c(6,11),labRow = "" ,trace="none",keysize = 1.2,density.info="none",main="MTL",srtCol=90)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `breaks` argument:

```
library(gplots)
Gold <- matrix(runif(300, -0.15, 0.2), ncol=15)
colors = c(seq(min(Gold),-0.0002,length=100),seq(-0.0003,0.0002,length=20),seq(0.0003,max(Gold),length=100))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","white","yellow", "red"))(n = 219)
my_breaks <- seq(-0.2, 0.2, length.out=length(my_palette)+1) 
heatmap.2(Gold, col=my_palette, breaks=my_breaks)
```